# devise/omniauth - The action 'facebook' could not be found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to implement facebook authentication in my app following [this guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)

I've followed all the steps but get the following error after hitting  login.

```
Unknown action

The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
```

I've created the file omniauth_callbacks_controller in controllers/users. It has a facebook method defined. Any idea how I should debug?

---

Adding my routes file  -

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "static_pages/home"

  get "static_pages/help"

  get "static_pages/about"

  devise_for :users do
    resources :posts

  end

  root :to => 'static_pages#home'

  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
end
```

Comment: Same issue here

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look at the guide it specifies this line for your routes file:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

where you have:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that your users will be able to login and logout, edit profile, register with facebook or register with email and also you may add Confirmable to devise if you want. You should have extra columns in users table. Something like adding extra fields into your user model first.

`rails g migration AddFieledsToUser provider:string uid:string image:string`

then run `rails db:migrate`

Check your users table ensure you have these 3 columns above

Also I am assuming that you you have correctly configured initializers/devise.rb like so: `config.omniauth :facebook, 'APP_ID', 'APP_SECRET_KEY', scope: 'email', info_fields: 'email, name'` after you've properly created the facebook app. Also assuming you have properly created and configured your `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb` based on the gems `gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6'` and `gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'` in your gem file successfully. Just make sure you have all these steps done.

In your routes.rb you can add this:

```
devise_for :users,
         path: '',
         path_names: {
           sign_in: 'login',
           sign_out: 'logout',
           edit: 'profile',
           sign_up: 'registration'
         },
         controllers: {
           omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks',
         }
```

I think this is the part you have missed. You can also name the routes whatever you want. Just saying.

Comment: I still get The action 'facebook' could not be found for Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController, how can I debug it?

Comment: did you create an omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb inside your controller folder? inside that file should be a class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController. Just open the file and check if the action facebook is there.

Comment: Otherwise maybe try to update your gem file and remove omniauth gem.

      gem 'devise', '=4.7.2'
      gem 'omniauth-facebook'
      # gem 'omniauth', '= 1.9.0'

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with tutorials.  Check the capitalization of 
F in facebook in users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb  I was using a capital "Facebook" but it was looking for lowercase "facebook"